# I can't get mouse aiming to work properly

Tags: javascript, html, math, canvas

I am trying to make my gray square point at the mouse, I did the calculations but something is not right as the aiming (yellow rectangle) is not directly at the mouse location. It works but in a weird way.

The code where I do the angle and rotation calculations is the following:

```
//Get angle:
angleToTurn = -Math.atan2(mouseX - (500+25), mouseY - (250+25))*(180/Math.PI);
//Rotate the object:
//Observation, 500 is the objects x location and 250 is it's y
var rad = (angleToTurn * (Math.PI / 180))+90;
ctx.translate((500+25) + robots.width/2,(250+25) + robots.height/2)
ctx.rotate(rad);
robots.x = (robots.width / 2) * (-1);
robots.y = (robots.height / 2) * (-1);
robots.drawn();
ctx.rotate(rad * ( -1 ));
ctx.translate(((500+25) + (robots.width / 2)) * (-1), ((250+25) + (robots.height / 2)) * (-1));
```

The objective is to make the square aim, yellow rectangle, point exactly at the mouse position (blue square).

---

Off topic

I need help to improve my questions. If you have any suggestions, tell me what should I do to make this question better. I would be very happy to receive some orientation.

```js
var canvas, ctx, intervalo, players, robots, mouseX, mouseY;

function load() {
  canvas = document.getElementById('box');
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  function player(health, width, height, speed, x, y) {
    this.health = health;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.speed = speed;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    this.up = false;
    this.down = false;
    this.left = false;
    this.right = false;

    this.drawn = function() {
      ctx.fillStyle = "red";
      ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    }
  }
  var Player = new Array();
  Player.push(new player(50, 5, 5, 3, 200, canvas.height / 2));
  players = Player[0];

  function inteligentRobot(width, height, x, y) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    this.drawn = function() {
      ctx.fillStyle = "gray";
      ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
      ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
      ctx.fillRect(this.x + this.width, this.y + (this.height / 2), this.width * 2, this.height / 10)

      if ((players.x > this.x - this.width) &&
        (players.x < this.x) &&
        (players.y < this.y + this.height) &&
        (players.y > this.y)) {

      }
    }
  }
  var iaRobot = new Array();
  iaRobot.push(new inteligentRobot(50, 50, 500, 250));
  robots = iaRobot[0];

  var keyUp, keyDown, keyLeft, keyRight;
  keyUp = 87;
  keyDown = 83;
  keyLeft = 65;
  keyRight = 68;
  window.addEventListener('keydown', checkKeyDown, false);

  function checkKeyDown(e) {
    if (event.keyCode == keyUp) {
      players.up = true;
    } else if (event.keyCode == keyDown) {
      players.down = true;
    } else if (event.keyCode == keyLeft) {
      players.left = true;
    } else if (event.keyCode == keyRight) {
      players.right = true;
    }
  }

  window.addEventListener("keyup", checkKeyUp, false);

  function checkKeyUp(e) {
    if (event.keyCode == keyUp) {
      players.up = false;
    } else if (event.keyCode == keyDown) {
      players.down = false;
    } else if (event.keyCode == keyLeft) {
      players.left = false;
    } else if (event.keyCode == keyRight) {
      players.right = false;
    }
  }

  //Mouse position
  document.onmousemove = mouseMove;

  function mouseMove(event) {
    event = event || canvas.event
    mouseX = event.pageX;
    mouseY = event.pageY;
    mouseX = mouseX - 11;
    mouseY = mouseY - 13;
  }
}

function play() {
  intevalo = setInterval(animation, 1000 / 60)
}

function animation() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  if (players.up) {
    players.y -= players.speed;
  }
  if (players.down) {
    players.y += players.speed;
  }
  if (players.left) {
    players.x -= players.speed;
  }
  if (players.right) {
    players.x += players.speed;
  }
  //Get angle:
  angleToTurn = -Math.atan2(mouseX - (500 + 25), mouseY - (250 + 25)) * (180 / Math.PI);
  //Rotate the object:
  var rad = (angleToTurn * Math.PI / 180) + 90;
  ctx.translate((500 + 25) + robots.width / 2, (250 + 25) + robots.height / 2)
  ctx.rotate(rad);
  robots.x = (robots.width / 2) * (-1);
  robots.y = (robots.height / 2) * (-1);
  robots.drawn();
  ctx.rotate(rad * (-1));
  ctx.translate(((500 + 25) + (robots.width / 2)) * (-1), ((250 + 25) + (robots.height / 2)) * (-1));
  //Mouse pointer location:
  ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
  ctx.fillRect(mouseX, mouseY, 5, 5);
  players.drawn();
}
```

```css
#box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-color: white;
}
#button {
  border: none;
  background-color: gray;
  width: 70;
  height: 50;
}
canvas {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
html {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-family: courier new;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilo.css">
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="load()">
  <canvas id="box" width="1330" height="500"></canvas>
  <button onclick="play()" id="button">Play</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Note that the natural call format for the argument function is `atan2( dy, dx)` in mathematically positively oriented cartesian coordinates. Since on screen the y direction points down, this has to be modified to `atan2(-dy,dx)`, which then requires no correction by 90°.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of problems, first `(500+25) + robots.width/2` I presume that 25 is suppose to be `robots.width/2` so you are adding it twice. Second `(angleToTurn * (Math.PI / 180))+90`, 90 is in degrees but `(angleToTurn * (Math.PI / 180))` is in radians. I'm not sure why you are the translation back and forth in the first place atan2 returns radians.

I'm not a JS Dev, but I'm not sure that rotating and translating the canvas, drawing the object, then rotating and translating back is the best way to do things, it seems confusing to me. seems it should be easier to translate and rotate the object it self.

In any case I made some correction and it seems to work, take a look at the code:

```js
var canvas, ctx, intervalo, players, robots, mouseX, mouseY;

function load() {
  canvas = document.getElementById('box');
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  function player(health, width, height, speed, x, y) {
    this.health = health;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.speed = speed;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    this.up = false;
    this.down = false;
    this.left = false;
    this.right = false;

    this.drawn = function() {
      ctx.fillStyle = "red";
      ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    }
  }
  var Player = new Array();
  Player.push(new player(50, 5, 5, 3, 200, canvas.height / 2));
  players = Player[0];

  function inteligentRobot(width, height, x, y) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    this.drawn = function() {
      ctx.fillStyle = "gray";
      ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
      ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
      ctx.fillRect(this.x + this.width, this.y + (this.height / 2), this.width * 2, this.height / 10)

      if ((players.x > this.x - this.width) &&
        (players.x < this.x) &&
        (players.y < this.y + this.height) &&
        (players.y > this.y)) {

      }
    }
  }
  var iaRobot = new Array();
  iaRobot.push(new inteligentRobot(50, 50, 500, 250));
  robots = iaRobot[0];

  var keyUp, keyDown, keyLeft, keyRight;
  keyUp = 87;
  keyDown = 83;
  keyLeft = 65;
  keyRight = 68;
  window.addEventListener('keydown', checkKeyDown, false);

  function checkKeyDown(e) {
    if (event.keyCode == keyUp) {
      players.up = true;
    } else if (event.keyCode == keyDown) {
      players.down = true;
    } else if (event.keyCode == keyLeft) {
      players.left = true;
    } else if (event.keyCode == keyRight) {
      players.right = true;
    }
  }

  window.addEventListener("keyup", checkKeyUp, false);

  function checkKeyUp(e) {
    if (event.keyCode == keyUp) {
      players.up = false;
    } else if (event.keyCode == keyDown) {
      players.down = false;
    } else if (event.keyCode == keyLeft) {
      players.left = false;
    } else if (event.keyCode == keyRight) {
      players.right = false;
    }
  }

  //Mouse position
  document.onmousemove = mouseMove;

  function mouseMove(event) {
    event = event || canvas.event
    mouseX = event.pageX;
    mouseY = event.pageY;
    mouseX = mouseX - 11;
    mouseY = mouseY - 13;
  }
}

function play() {
  intevalo = setInterval(animation, 1000 / 60)
}

function animation() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  if (players.up) {
    players.y -= players.speed;
  }
  if (players.down) {
    players.y += players.speed;
  }
  if (players.left) {
    players.x -= players.speed;
  }
  if (players.right) {
    players.x += players.speed;
  }
  //Get angle:
  angleToTurn = -Math.atan2(mouseX - (500+ robots.width / 2), mouseY - (250 + robots.height / 2)) ;
  //Rotate the object:
  var rad = angleToTurn + Math.PI/2;
  ctx.translate(500 + (robots.width / 2), 250 + (robots.height / 2))
  ctx.rotate(rad);
  robots.x = (robots.width / 2) * (-1);
  robots.y = (robots.height / 2) * (-1);
  robots.drawn();
  ctx.rotate(rad * (-1));
  ctx.translate((500 + (robots.width / 2)) * (-1), (250 + (robots.height / 2)) * (-1));
  //Mouse pointer location:
  ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
  ctx.fillRect(mouseX, mouseY, 5, 5);
  players.drawn();
}
```

```css
#box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-color: white;
}
#button {
  border: none;
  background-color: gray;
  width: 70;
  height: 50;
}
canvas {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
html {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-family: courier new;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilo.css">
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="load()">
  <canvas id="box" width="1330" height="500"></canvas>
  <button onclick="play()" id="button">Play</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Canvas way of rotating things is in fact very weird. Thanks for the info, I wasn't very sure of how all that worked.